# Form Submitting Data Before Submit Button is Pressed

Tags: php, mysql, sql, forms

I have a form/page that seems to submit the form data when the page loads. If you click "add record" it loads the page and creates a new entry into the database without entering any information. If you complete the form it works as desired but creates and additional record. What would cause the form to submit "on load"? Also I use this same form for other areas of the site with no issue but the data is stored into a different table.

My Code

```
    <?

    if(isset($_POST['title'])) {
        if(isset($_POST['gallery_1'])) {
            $gallery_1 = $_POST['gallery_1'];
        }
        if(isset($_POST['gallery_2'])) {
            $gallery_2 = $_POST['gallery_2'];
        }
            if(isset($_POST['gallery_3'])) {
            $gallery_3 = $_POST['gallery_3'];
        }
            if(isset($_POST['gallery_4'])) {
            $gallery_4 = $_POST['gallery_4'];
        }
            if(isset($_POST['gallery_5'])) {
            $gallery_5 = $_POST['gallery_5'];
        }

            if(isset($_POST['download_1'])) {
            $download_1 = $_POST['download_1'];
        }

            if(isset($_POST['download_2'])) {
            $download_2 = $_POST['download_2'];
        }

            if(isset($_POST['download_3'])) {
            $download_3 = $_POST['download_3'];
        }

        $title = $_POST['title'];
        $title_gallery = $_POST['title_gallery'];
        $date = $_POST['date'];
        $introduction = $_POST['introduction'];
        $download_1_title = $_POST['download_1_title'];
        $download_2_title = $_POST['download_2_title'];
        $download_3_title = $_POST['download_3_title'];
        $dropbox_title = $_POST['dropbox_title'];
        $dropbox_info = $_POST['dropbox_info'];
        $dropbox_link = $_POST['dropbox_link'];
        $video_title = $_POST['video_title'];
        $video = $_POST['video'];


        $handle = new Upload($_FILES['gallery_1']);
            if ($handle->uploaded) {
                $handle->file_max_size = 4000000;
                $handle->image_resize = true;
                $handle->image_ratio = true;
                $handle->image_ratio_crop = true;
                $handle->image_y = 407;
                $handle->image_x = 460;
                $handle->allowed = array('image/pjpeg','image/jpeg', 'image/jpg');
                $handle->Process($dir_dest);
                if ($handle->processed) {
                    echo 'issue image 1 uploaded ' . round(filesize($handle->file_dst_pathname)/256)/4 . 'KB<br /><br />';
                    $gallery_1 = $dir_pics.'/' . $handle->file_dst_name ;
                } else {
                    echo '  the following error occurred while uploading image 1<br />';
                    echo '  Error: ' . $handle->error . '<br /><br />';
                }
                $handle-> Clean();
            }



            $handle2 = new Upload($_FILES['gallery_2']);
            if ($handle2->uploaded) {
                $handle2->file_max_size = 4000000;
                $handle2->image_resize = true;
                $handle2->image_ratio = true;
                $handle2->image_ratio_crop = true;
                $handle2->image_y = 307;
                $handle2->image_x = 460;
                $handle2->allowed = array('image/pjpeg','image/jpeg', 'image/jpg');
                $handle2->Process($dir_dest);
                if ($handle2->processed) {
                    echo 'issue image 2 uploaded ' . round(filesize($handle2->file_dst_pathname)/256)/4 . 'KB<br /><br />';
                    $gallery_2 = $dir_pics.'/' . $handle2->file_dst_name ;
                } else {
                    echo '  the following error occurred while uploading image 2<br />';
                    echo '  Error: ' . $handle2->error . '<br /><br />';
                }
                $handle2-> Clean();
            }

            $handle3 = new Upload($_FILES['gallery_3']);
            if ($handle3->uploaded) {
                $handle3->file_max_size = 4000000;
                $handle3->image_resize = true;
                $handle3->image_ratio = true;
                $handle3->image_ratio_crop = true;
                $handle3->image_y = 307;
                $handle3->image_x = 460;
                $handle3->allowed = array('image/pjpeg','image/jpeg', 'image/jpg');
                $handle3->Process($dir_dest);
                if ($handle3->processed) {
                    echo 'issue image 3 uploaded ' . round(filesize($handle3->file_dst_pathname)/256)/4 . 'KB<br /><br />';
                    $gallery_3 = $dir_pics.'/' . $handle3->file_dst_name ;
                } else {
                    echo '  the following error occurred while uploading image 3<br />';
                    echo '  Error: ' . $handle3->error . '<br /><br />';
                }
                $handle3-> Clean();
            }

            $handle4 = new Upload($_FILES['gallery_4']);
            if ($handle4->uploaded) {
                $handle4->file_max_size = 4000000;
                $handle4->image_resize = true;
                $handle4->image_ratio = true;
                $handle4->image_ratio_crop = true;
                $handle4->image_y = 307;
                $handle4->image_x = 460;
                $handle4->allowed = array('image/pjpeg','image/jpeg', 'image/jpg');
                $handle4->Process($dir_dest);
                if ($handle4->processed) {
                    echo 'main image for issue uploaded ' . round(filesize($handle4->file_dst_pathname)/256)/4 . 'KB<br /><br />';
                    $gallery_4 = $dir_pics.'/' . $handle4->file_dst_name ;
                } else {
                    echo '  the following error occurred while uploading the main image<br />';
                    echo '  Error: ' . $handle4->error . '<br /><br />';
                }
                $handle4-> Clean();
            }

            $handle5 = new Upload($_FILES['gallery_5']);
            if ($handle5->uploaded) {
                $handle5->file_max_size = 4000000;
                $handle5->image_resize = true;
                $handle5->image_ratio = true;
                $handle5->image_ratio_crop = true;
                $handle5->image_y = 307;
                $handle5->image_x = 460;
                $handle5->allowed = array('image/pjpeg','image/jpeg', 'image/jpg');
                $handle5->Process($dir_dest);
                if ($handle5->processed) {
                    echo 'map image for issue uploaded ' . round(filesize($handle5->file_dst_pathname)/256)/4 . 'KB<br /><br />';
                    $gallery_5 = $dir_pics.'/' . $handle5->file_dst_name ;
                } else {
                    echo '  the following error occurred while uploading the map image<br />';
                    echo '  Error: ' . $handle5->error . '<br /><br />';
                }
                $handle5-> Clean();
            }


            $handle6 = new Upload($_FILES['download_1']);
            if ($handle6->uploaded) {
                $handle6->file_max_size = 4000000;
                $handle6->allowed = array('application/*', 'image/*');
                $handle6->Process($dir_dest);
                if ($handle6->processed) {
                    echo 'download one uploaded' . round(filesize($handle6->file_dst_pathname)/256)/4 . 'KB<br /><br />';
                    $download_1 = $dir_pics.'/' . $handle6->file_dst_name ;
                } else {
                    echo '  the following error occurred while uploading download one<br />';
                    echo '  Error: ' . $handle6->error . '<br /><br />';
                }
                $handle6-> Clean();
            }

            $handle7 = new Upload($_FILES['download_2']);
            if ($handle7->uploaded) {
                $handle->file_max_size = 4000000;
                $handle->allowed = array('application/*', 'image/*');
                $handle7->Process($dir_dest);
                if ($handle7->processed) {
                    echo 'download two uploaded' . round(filesize($handle7->file_dst_pathname)/256)/4 . 'KB<br /><br />';
                    $download_2 = $dir_pics.'/' . $handle7->file_dst_name ;
                } else {
                    echo '  the following error occurred while uploading download two<br />';
                    echo '  Error: ' . $handle7->error . '<br /><br />';
                }
                $handle7-> Clean();
            }

            $handle8 = new Upload($_FILES['download_3']);
            if ($handle8->uploaded) {
                $handle->file_max_size = 4000000;
                $handle->allowed = array('application/*', 'image/*');
                $handle8->Process($dir_dest);
                if ($handle8->processed) {
                    echo 'download three uploaded' . round(filesize($handle8->file_dst_pathname)/256)/4 . 'KB<br /><br />';
                    $download_3 = $dir_pics.'/' . $handle8->file_dst_name ;
                } else {
                    echo '  the following error occurred while uploading download three<br />';
                    echo '  Error: ' . $handle8->error . '<br /><br />';
                }
                $handle8-> Clean();
            }


        }

        $query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO news  (
id ,
title ,
title_gallery ,
date ,
introduction ,
gallery_1 ,
gallery_2 ,
gallery_3 ,
gallery_4 ,
gallery_5 ,
download_1 ,
download_2 ,
download_3 ,
download_1_title ,
download_2_title ,
download_3_title ,
dropbox_title ,
dropbox_info ,
dropbox_link ,
video_title ,
video
) VALUES

(NULL,
'$title',
'$title_gallery',
'$date',
'$introduction',
'$gallery_1',
'$gallery_2',
'$gallery_3',
'$gallery_4',
'$gallery_5',
'$download_1',
'$download_2',
'$download_3',
'$download_1_title',
'$download_2_title',
'$download_3_title',
'$dropbox_title',
'$dropbox_info',
'$dropbox_link',
'$video_title',
'$video');");

if($query) {
            $message = $title . " has been added";
        }else{
            $message = "an error occurred while updating this entry";
        }


    ?>
    </p>

    <? if(isset($_POST['title'])) { ?>
            <div id="content_holder">
              <p style="text-align:center;padding-top:20px;">
              <strong><? echo $message; ?></strong><br/>
              <span class="error"><? if($error_message) { echo $error_message; } ?></span>
              Add another <a href="add.php">Record/Item</a></p>
            <!-- end content_holder -->
            </div>
       <? }else{ ?>
```

The form... and Closing brackets...

Comment: I don't think it is possible. Can you post the code?

Comment: Are you using Javascript? That would be the only culprit here I imagine.

Comment: are you checking if the submit button has been pressed? if (isset($_POST['Submit'])){ check other values and send to database }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `INSERT` query is outside your `if(isset($_POST['title']))` statement. A row is inserted on every page load with empty values.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible on the php side of things you do not check if the form was submited and just blindly create a new record from empty data every time the page loads?

edit: exactly. The mysql query runs no mather what. Put a if around it to make sure a form was submited.